# Helm template - Overriding values file

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am currently trying to test some changes, specifically to see if a chart picks up/inherits changes from a top level values file. This top level values file should override any settings in the values file for this chart. To test this, I am trying to use the following command:

`helm template --values path/to/top/level/values.yaml path/to/chart > output.yaml`

However, when viewing the output for this, the chart still retains the values defined in the chart, and not the values that have been set in the top level values file.

I have tried a number of variations of this command, such as:

`helm template path/to/chart --values path/to/top/level/values.yaml > output.yaml`

`helm template -f path/to/chart/values.yaml --values path/to/top/level/values.yaml > output.yaml`

`helm template path/to/top/level/values.yaml --values path/to/chart > output.yaml`

Am I using this command correctly? Is what I am trying to achieve only possible when doing a helm install or upgrade? e.g. https://all.docs.genesys.com/PrivateEdition/Current/PEGuide/HelmOverrides

Comment: The `helm template` syntax seems fine (you shouldn't need to directly reference the chart's own `values.yaml` file).  Do the layouts of the two YAML files match?  Are you expecting the chart you're testing to be deployed as a subchart of the top-level chart, or is the top-level values file something that could be used in a standalone installation (maybe using a tool like Helmsman or Helmfile)?

Answer (score 2):

Overriding values from a parent (you call it top-level) chart `mychart` works like a charm and exactly as described in the [Helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/#overriding-values-from-a-parent-chart).

A `values.yaml` in folder `mychart/charts/mysubchart`

```
dessert: cake
```

can be overriden by a `values.yaml` in folder `mychart`

```
mysubchart:
  dessert: ice cream
```

Any directives inside of the `mysubchart` section will be sent to the `mysubchart` chart.

Rendering the parent (top-level) chart works like that:

```
helm template mychart -f mychart/values.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I don't think that works. This is what I have ran:


`helm template path/to/chart -f external/dir/path/to/values.yaml > output.yaml`


Viewing the output still shows that the chart retains the values set in the chart itself, rather than be overridden the values file (which is in a different repo/directory).

Comment: I suggest to add more details to your question especially absolute file paths, commands, command output and expected command output.

Comment: Hi, I managed to get it working in the end. The solution that worked for in the end was: helm template --values external/dir/path/to/values.yaml path/to/chart > output.yaml

Comment: `--values` is nothing else than `-f` - see `helm template --help`. The order of [Chart] and [flags] does not matter for this specific case. I recommend to align with order of arguments given in help/command usage.

Answer (score 0):

What if what you want is to combine from 2 yaml files, is it possible?

Example:

values.yaml:

```
blackBoxSidecar:
  enabled: true
  targets:
    - target: esb:443
      module: tcp_connect
```

values-namespace.yaml:

```
blackBoxSidecar:
  targets:
    - target: rabbitmq-namespace:443
      module: tcp_connect
```

What I want to get is:

```
blackBoxSidecar:
  enabled: true
  targets:
    - target: esb:443
      module: tcp_connect
    - target: rabbitmq-namespace:443
      module: tcp_connect
```

Comment: Found it:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1087674/helm-how-to-add-elements-to-a-list-of-default-values